# SSIS to do Insert, Update, and Deletes

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have been able to get my SSIS process to handle the Insert and Updates using Sorts, Merge Join, and conditional split.

I am not sure how I could handle the delete on my destination table because my merge join is a left join operation off the source (So I can handle inserts).  How have others handled this scnerio? I tried changing to a full outer join so I could look for a null in the source, but that didn't seem to work?

Flow (Sources: Source and Destination, Sorts: Source and Destination, Merge Join, Conditional Split: Insert and Update).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will be what you want to do, but since the question has no responses, thought I would mention `MERGE` If you are running SQL Server 2008.  You could add a SQL Task to SSIS and code the query handle the inserts, updates, deletes, or any subset as needed:

Here is the MS documentation:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx